# inserting javascript code in a meteor project: best practice

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I have a meteor project, and I have a `client` folder (seen only by the client), a `server` folder (seen only by the server) and a `lib` folder (seen by both client and server).

I have in `/client/devices` two files, `devices.html` and `devices.js`, that are parts of an HTML page.

I have to insert in this page [this](https://atmospherejs.com/richsilv/pikaday) date picker: however, the instructions says
 that I have to insert at **bottom** of the page (so it can be loaded after the page is completely loaded) this line:

```
var picker = new Pikaday({ field: document.getElementById('datepicker') });
```

I tried to put it directly after the  tag, in a  tag; and it works:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
<script>
    var picker = new Pikaday({ field: document.getElementById('datepicker') });
</script>
```

I tried also to put it in `Template.devices.onRendered` but it does not work.

my question is: since I'm not sure if it is a good practice to put code in the middle of an html file, where should I put this part?

Comment: Did you `meteor add richsilv:pikaday`?

Comment: yep, it works, I'm just not sure where to put that piece of code because I'm quite new with meteor

Comment: What happens when you put the initialization in `Template.devices.onRendered`? You say it didn't work - are there any errors?

Comment: Also, I'd recommend using the `npm` version instead of the meteor package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pikaday (`npm install pikaday`)

Comment: a. It says `TypeError: from[prop] is null` probably referred to imported files
b. I tried the npm version: I have the same problem - I need a place where to put the line above - plus I need a place where to put the `import` line. I didn't find a right place where to put them, so it didn't work, so I switched to the meteor package - at least I have no troubles with the import :)

Comment: Hmm... not sure what's going on then. I'll do some digging around.

Comment: Is this a typo? `<input type="text" id="datepickerTo">` You call it _datepickerTo_ but initialize with _datepicker_

Comment: yes, sorry! typo, corrected

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things you need to do to ensure that 3rd party code will work in a Meteor app.

1. Ensure you've installed the package either through Atmosphere or `npm`.
2. Import the package in the file you want to use it.
3. Initialize the code when the UI is ready.

For example:

**client/main.html**

```
<body>
  {{> devices}}
</body>

<template name="devices">
  <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</template>
```

**client/main.js**

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import Pikaday from 'pikaday';

import './main.html';

Template.devices.onRendered(function devicesOnRendered() {
  new Pikaday({ field: document.getElementById('datepicker') });
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.4",
    "pikaday": "latest"
  }
}
```

---

#### Meteor Guide on Packaging

https://guide.meteor.com/atmosphere-vs-npm.html
https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#importing-from-packages

Comment: this does not work, in main.js could not find

`import Pikaday from 'pikaday';`

`import './main.html';`

Comment: @Diego My point was just to make an MVCE showing that this will work. You may be doing something that you did not provide in the question that is the culprit. Try paring down your project (or starting a new bare-bones one) and trying to get it to work and see what the differences are.